# Add expanders for long questions

Tags: feature-request

*I apologize if this has already been brought up. I didn't find it in a search.*

I tend to post very verbose questions due to the nature of what I'm doing. It's extremely difficult to make a minimal example since it's all entangled in multithreading, views-within-views, multiple ViewModels, etc. So, I try to instead explain what's going on, and mention all of the things I've tried, to see if someone has **insight** or **suggestions**, not necessarily a concrete answer.

Unfortunately, I think this has the effect of scaring people off due to TL;DR. So far, I haven't gotten feedback on most of them. But, if I try to trim down the problem, I know it's going to end up with "provide more information" and "show some code" -- which ends up in the verbose format anyways.

So, I was thinking that if there was a way to wrap content in expanders, I could provide the "quick and dirty" at the top, and then put details in expander sections that people can expand if they want to contribute to the question/problem. It would also allow people who come across it later after it's been answered to just see a quick view of the problem followed by the answer -- with all of the details intact in collapsed expanders.

I've done this with wikis in the past for things like large tables of information, and it was very handy.

Once I have a solution for a question, I'm going to remove the then-useless or misleading information, but in the meantime, I don't want to be scaring off feedback.

Comment: This definitely was asked before (at least on MSE), and I think it was declined.

Answer (score 3):

I have reviewed *all* of your questions, there were only 6 :)

I don't see any that I consider to be excessively long. Sometimes in order to paint the full picture in a complex environment you need to include several snippets or explanations. So long as the explanations are minimal, even if they take some space, there is nothing wrong with that.

I am rather familiar with the technology you are using. I use it. Even Stack Overflow uses it!

So, my advice would be not to worry about a question getting a little lengthy as long as it is all topical and not just one massive code dump. By the way, thank you for not code dumping, that is a real issue with these large posts.

As far as issues go, expanders would not have improved any of your questions. That would have just hidden information that was already required to examine. Furthermore, expanders have a very high potential to be misused in other posts by different users less inclined to post nice concise questions.

The potential for abuse paired with my opinion that these expanders would not have helped in your questions (nor in general I believe) are the reason why I don't think this feature would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've been an engineer for way too long, so I usually try to be as concise as I can. I also was a moderator for a VB6 forum for many years, so I tend to understand the general format. I had many design suggestions implemented there, as well as on the wikis I heavily contributed to, so I thought I'd toss this one out. Really only one of my questions was bothering me (the one with 4+ edits). I can see the potential for abuse, but that's already done with the snippet tags that I edit out. --- Now if I can just figure out how to be on Meta without getting downvoted...

Comment: @ChrisFannin - Don't take feature downvotes to heart, it is just about the feature and not about the post. I feel like you framed the issue well, it is just that downvoting on feature requests indicate disagreement with the suggested feature more than anything to do with the presentation of the feature. Going forward, there tends to be better results when starting an unbiased discussion with regards to the problem that a feature would solve and trying to get a consensus for a feature - and then post that feature request - than it is to just skip to posting it right away.